# Can´t find assembly from other project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I having trouble finding assembly from a project. I have two Console Applications and one where i make a reference from the other. But then i can´t make the using-statement because it can´t find the project...

[image: picture of error]

---

EDIT: my Program-class in Lab1PersonId:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Lab1PersonId
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
         {
        }
     }
 }
```

---

EDIT:

```
using Lab1PersonId;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Lab1PersonId lab = new Lab1PersonId();   ***
        }
    }
 }
```

Error on row ***:
Type name expected, but namespace named found

Comment: Did you build the solutuon?

Comment: yes i have, no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup seems fine. You have added reference to the `Lab1PersonId` project inside your Test project, so normally you should be able to use classes that are defined in this assembly.

For example, you should first rebuild the `Lab1PersonId` project and then you should be able to add reference to some namespace that exists in it:

```
using Lab1PersonId;
```

Comment: @daniel_aren, what error are you getting? Also which class do you want to use from the `Lab1PersonId` project? I can see that you only have one class currently - `Program.cs`. Could you show it?

Comment: it´s just a class with a Main-method, nothing else.. i have added one more class now but still the same.. i don´t get any error i dont´t get it at the intelicense when i try to include it with my using. If i still write it and make a new instance it says: can´t find assembly..

Comment: Is your class defined as `public`? Don't forget that you cannot access classes which are not public from different assemblies. Is this class defined inside a namespace? Once again, could you please show your `Program.cs` code? It's hard to help you if you are not showing your code.

Comment: How are you trying to call the `Program` class? This class doesn't have any public method. It only has a single method called Main, this method is static and not public, so you cannot call it from a different assembly.

Comment: Lab1PersonId lab = new Lab1PersonId();

Comment: now i saw the error, i used: Lab1PersonId.Program lab = new Lab1PersonId.Program(); it worked, thanks for helping